# Combinatorics: how many different subsequences of length i can we choose from a sequence of length j?

Tags: combinatorics

The subsequences cannot change the order of the original sequence.

I read somewhere that the answer is $j - (i - 1)$ but I don't understand the reasoning.

I'm also unsure about what topic this is.

Comment: To clarify, the subsequence you want must consist of consecutive terms?  If the original sequence is $abc$ then I'd say the length two subsequences were $ab,bc,ac$.  But you say there are only $2=3-(2-1)$ of them so I suppose you are excluding $ac$.  Assuming that's right, then starting with the sequence $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^j$ the last term which could start the subsequence is $s_{j-(i-1)}$.

Comment: @lulu Ah. You're right.

Comment: You could also prove the formula by induction on $j$ (for a fixed $i$).  Worth noting (assuming the confusion comes from it being $j-(i-1)$ and not $j-i$, these ["off-by-one" or "fencepost" errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) are ubiquitous.  It's always a good idea to write out explicit examples.

Comment: @lulu Yeah the "off-by-one" error was one of the things I was confused about. It does indeed help to write out explicit examples. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the letters in your sequence are $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_j$. Since the terms in the subsequence cannot change in their order, the subsequence cannot start later than $a_{j-i+1}$.

EDIT : Please see [@lulu's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884173/combinatorics-how-many-different-subsequences-of-length-i-can-we-choose-from-a/1884180#comment3862955_1884173) (quoted below). I had already assumed that point because of the form of the answer given by the OP.

> To clarify, the subsequence you want must consist of consecutive terms? If the original sequence is $abc$ then I'd say the length two subsequences were $ab,bc,ac$. But you say there are only $2=3−(2−1)$ of them so I suppose you are excluding $ac$. Assuming that's right, then starting with the sequence $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^j$ the last term which could start the subsequence is $s_{j-(i-1)}$. – lulu Aug 6 '16 at 11:37